# Icon does not appear on TabbedPage

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

Please see the XAML below:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem
    Command="{Binding SettingsCommand}"
    Text="Settings">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="app_settings" />
                <On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets/app_settings.png" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<TabbedPage.Title>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <On Platform="iOS, UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="MyNamespace" />
    </OnPlatform>
</TabbedPage.Title>

<views:TestEnquiriesView
  x:Name="TestView">
    <views:TestEnquiriesView.Title>Test</views:TestEnquiriesView.Title>
</views:TestEnquiriesView>

<views:ProfileView
  x:Name="ProfileView">
    <views:ProfileView.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="menu_profile" />
            <On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets\menu_profile.png" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </views:ProfileView.Icon>
</views:ProfileView>
```

app_settings.png and menu_profile.png display correctly on Android, however only menu_profile.png displays on UWP.  Why?

Incidentally there are two warnings on the page:

1) `The attachable property ToolbarItems was not found in type ContentPage` on this line:  `<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>`.

2) `The property default is set more than once` on this line: `<On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets\menu_profile.png" />`

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `/` to `\`.

use code:

```
<On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets\app_settings.png" />
```

instead of

```
<On Platform="UWP, WinRT, WinPhone" Value="Assets/app_settings.png" />
```